# JS output array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
[
    {'id': 123, 'name': 'apples', 'total': 30},
    {'id': 541, 'name': 'oranges', 'total': 42},
    {'id': 300, 'name': 'bananas', 'total': 18}
]
```

How do I output this array in a form like that:

```
Apples: 30
Oranges: 42
Bananas: 18
```

I tried

```js
let myArray = [{
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'apples',
    'total': 30
  },
  {
    'id': 541,
    'name': 'oranges',
    'total': 42
  },
  {
    'id': 300,
    'name': 'bananas',
    'total': 18
  }
]
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray.map(a => a.name)))
```

but that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: `a => a.name+ ':'+ a.total+'\n'`

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I'm assuming you mean to use string template. If yes, try escaping \`. Its `\\``

Comment: @mikebrsv, question is, what format do you wish to save? String or array?

Comment: ```myArray.map(a => `${a.name}: ${a.total}`)```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` with spread syntax and to create an object from array.

```js
const data = [{'id': 123, 'name': 'apples', 'total': 30},{'id': 541, 'name': 'oranges', 'total': 42},{'id': 300, 'name': 'bananas', 'total': 18}]

const cap = str => str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
const result = Object.assign(...data.map(({name, total}) => ({[cap(name)]: total})))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate the array

```js
let arr = [{
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'apples',
    'total': 30
  },
  {
    'id': 541,
    'name': 'oranges',
    'total': 42
  },
  {
    'id': 300,
    'name': 'bananas',
    'total': 18
  }
]

arr.forEach((element) => {

  // do stuff with data
  let id = element.id;
  let name = element.name;
  let total = element.total;

  console.log(`${name}: ${total}`);

  // or write in div/form with innerHtml etc..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var data = [
    {'id': 123, 'name': 'apples', 'total': 30},
    {'id': 541, 'name': 'oranges', 'total': 42},
    {'id': 300, 'name': 'bananas', 'total': 18}
]

console.log(data.map(a => ({[a['name'].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a['name'].slice(1)]: a['total']})));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array will be something like this:

```
var fruits = [
    {'id': 123, 'name': 'apples', 'total': 30},
    {'id': 541, 'name': 'oranges', 'total': 42},
    {'id': 300, 'name': 'bananas', 'total': 18}
]
```

You can loop it for array using for loop.

```
for(i=0; i<fruits.length; i++)

{
    console.log(fruits[i].name + " : " + fruits[i].total);
}
```

It gives output you desire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this

```js
let data=[
    {'id': 123, 'name': 'apples', 'total': 30},
    {'id': 541, 'name': 'oranges', 'total': 42},
    {'id': 300, 'name': 'bananas', 'total': 18}
]

let update=Object.assign(...data.map(item=> ({[item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1)]:item.total})))

console.log(update);
```